# Publish different builds of a npm package to target different versions of node

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-publish

I'm have a small npm package which I'm writing in node 9 and using all the latest and greatest features like async/await. I'm also using babel which allows me to use ES6 module imports and exports

Babel also allows me to transpile the package to a target node version. I'm using the [node release schedule](https://github.com/nodejs/Release) to define which version of node the package will support and with the the target for the babel compilation. Currently node 4.x is still in maintenance lts stage, so I'm targeting it. Unfortunately this means almost every new feature in JavaScript I'm using gets transpiled.

What I'd like to do is to transpile the package to different targets (4.x, 6.x, 7.x, 8.x, and 9.x currently apply) and have npm choose the appropriate build of the package at install time based on the user's node version. If I'm not mistaken, I've seen apt-get do this with different versions of Ubuntu.

Is this possible with npm?

Answer (score 0):

I'll bump an old thread here. A good option is to use two separate directories and choose the transpiled version depending on [`process.version`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_version).

I'll be trying to do this in [`scramjet`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scramjet) and will be updating the thread along the way. My plan is to use an `index.js` file like this:

```
const ver = process.version.slice(1).split('.');
module.exports = require(+ver[0] > 8 && +ver[1] > 3 ? 'lib/index' : 'lib-6/index')
```

This should do for now, but since I also have some `v10+` targeted code (especially `DataStream.from(async function*() { ... })` which has some ifs in it I may want to extend it later and use a table.

What's important here is that the code above runs once (unless you clear require cache) and mostly in compile time so it has minimal influence over your module.